# WAR file: Could not find or load main class, but it’s there

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, war

I have built a WAR archive artifact with Intellij IDEA that contains a Spring Boot MVC application written in Kotlin.

Here’s the relevant contents:

```
$ jar tvf application.war
...
1649 [timestamp] WEB-INF/classes/org/domain/apps/App00HelloMvcKt.class
2087 [timestamp] WEB-INF/classes/org/domain/apps/App00HelloMvc.class
...
```

`App00HelloMvcKt` contains `fun main(...)`, and `App00HelloMvc` is the Spring Boot application class.

`MANIFEST.MF` contains `Main-Class` entry:

```
Main-Class: org.domain.apps.App00HelloMvcKt
```

However, when I run it, there is a problem:

```
$ java -jar application.war
Error: Could not find or load main class org.domain.apps.App00HelloMvcKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.domain.apps.App00HelloMvcKt
```

As I understand it, with this directory structure, no additional fumbling with class path is required. Then why is it unable to run?

---

Additional info: This is a teaching project. I am trying to serve `.jsp` pages from Spring Boot MVC application with embedded Tomcat. According to the internet, this setup only works if you package the app into a WAR and run it with `java -jar`.

Comment: How did you create the war? And do you really need JSP?

Comment: WAR is created as an Intellij IDEA project artifact, via ‘Web Application: Archive’ preset. As I’ve said, this is a teaching project, hence JSP. More to the point, I want to understand what goes wrong here, since I don’t see a reason for `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: Maybe its because a normal java -jar with Manifest mentioning main class will not look inside WEB-INF/classes folder for org.domain.apps.App00HelloMvcKt.class  It has to be packaged differently

Comment: You should use the spring boot plugin to create the war not simply export a war. using IntelliJ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely IntelliJ "Web Application: Archive" doesn't fully understand Spring Boot semantics. Try packaging the WAR with [Maven Spring Boot Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html), as in explained in chapter [68.2 Packaging Executable Jar and War Files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging):

```
$ mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage
$ java -jar target/application.war
```

Comment: Although, `.jsp` files still fail miserably with 404. But that is a story for another day.

Answer (score 0):

A jar file is simply a zip file, so do `zip -l application.war` and look to make sure your `App00HelloMvcKit` class is in there, and that your `MANIFEST.MF` is in the correct place.  One of these things is probably incorrect, so fix that.

If you can't figure it out, post the output of the above command in an edit to your question.